# fastapi-RuntimeError: attached to a different loop

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, fastapi

I use `fastapi` to do async work with `BackgroundTasks` in a `post` request to run a heavy task. And I have a `get` request to check the status of the heavy task.

```
from fastapi import BackgroundTasks

@router.post("/upload")
async def upload(background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    task_id = str(uuid.uuid1())
    background_tasks.add_task(run_task, task_id) 
    return {'code': 200, 'task_id': task_id, 'status': True}

@router.get("/status")
async def upload():
    task_id = str(uuid.uuid1())
    query = await MyModel.filter(task_id=task_id).first()
    return {'code': 200, 'status': query.status, 'status': True}
```

Because I have to use `db` in `long_time_task`, here I use `asyncio` in `run_task` to connect the two.

```
import asyncio
def run_task(task_id):
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    future = loop.create_task(long_time_task(task_id))
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait([future]))
    future.result()
```

Here is the `long_time_task`.

```
from tortoise import Tortoise
from dbs.database import TORTOISE_ORM

async def long_time_task(task_id):
    await Tortoise.init(config=TORTOISE_ORM)
    await Tortoise.generate_schemas()
    await MyModel.create(task_id=task_id)
```

Here if I send one or mutiple `post` request, everything goes well.

However if I send a `get` request, here comes a problem.

```
RuntimeError: Task <Task pending name='Task-17' coro=<RequestResponseCycle.run_asgi() running at /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/httptools_impl.py:404> cb=[set.discard()]> got Future <Task pending name='Task-18' coro=<Pool._wakeup() running at /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiomysql/pool.py:203>> attached to a different loop
```

The code which causes problem is `query = await MyModel.filter(task_id=task_id).first()`

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that FastAPI is already running an `asyncio` event loop, meaning you can't call `asyncio.run`. But, `BackgroundTask`s can be async, so there is no reason to not just do

```py
@router.post("/upload")
async def upload(background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    task_id = str(uuid.uuid1())
    background_tasks.add_task(long_time_task, task_id) 
    return {'code': 200, 'task_id': task_id, 'status': True}
```

and skip `run_task` altogether.